# mdx hierarchy XXX already appears in the axis0 axis

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I am trying to create an MDX sentence but I am getting this error: mdx hierarchy Article already appears in the axis0 axis. My question is... I get this error only when "Where" clause items are on columns or either in rows, how can I get a solution to this? Is there anyway to solve it without subselects?

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY { [Articles].[Article].[Article].ALLMEMBERS } ON COLUMNS  , 
NON EMPTY { [Measures].[%Uds] } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION ON ROWS 
FROM  [Modelo]  
WHERE  ( {[Articles].[Article].&[A] , 
[Articles].[Article].&[B]} )  CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One hierarchy can only appear in one axis (columns, rows, where) in MDX. Hence, when you want to restrict your selection, just do so directly on the columns axis and do not use the where clause at all:

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY {[Articles].[Article].&[A] , [Articles].[Article].&[B]} ON COLUMNS  , 
NON EMPTY { [Measures].[%Uds] } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION ON ROWS 
FROM  [Modelo]  
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

Alternatively, you could use a subselect:

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY { [Articles].[Article].[Article].ALLMEMBERS } ON COLUMNS  , 
NON EMPTY { [Measures].[%Uds] } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION ON ROWS 
FROM  (
    SELECT {[Articles].[Article].&[A] , [Articles].[Article].&[B]}
    FROM [Modelo]
    )  
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

There are some slight differences in the results between a subselect and where/direct reference in an axis, but in many cases the results are identical.

Comment: Is there any official document for referencing the line - One hierarchy can only appear in one axis (columns, rows, where) in MDX. 

If any please share.